# Samba file sharing is not working

Tags: windows, samba

I have done all configurations for file sharing from ubuntu to Windows following [this link](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-change-workgroup-ubuntu-linux-work-windows).

Now I am unable to access the ubuntu shared folder in Windows. I am getting access denied error.

Answer (score 2):

You must have shared in a way that it expects authorization. If so, you'll have to add a user to the samba configuration file or else you'll have to make the share accessible to everyone without authorization.

This link contains the details of creating samba shares :

http://www.pctips4u.com/2013/01/share-files-in-linux-over-network-using.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use samba package.

**To install Samba**

```
apt install samba -y
```

**To configure samba**

```
mkdir /path/to/fileshare

cp /etc/samba/smb.conf /etc/samba/smb.conf.bkup ; vim /etc/samba/smb.conf
```

**Write this in smb.conf file**

```
[fileshare_name]
path = /path/to/fileshare
read only = no
browsable = yes
```

Press : and write wq! to save configuration.

**Create user for samba**

```
adduser samba ; smbpasswd -a samba
```

**Restart samba**

```
systemctl restart smbd ; systemctl restart nmbd ; ufw allow 'Samba'
```

**Now try to connect from windows**

```
Win + R and write \\samba_server_ip'
```

Following this link https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-samba#4-setting-up-user-accounts-and-connecting-to-share